SSH with public key and google auth 2fa with whitelist ips
I'm trying to find a configuration that will required public key and 2fa by default but only public key from whitelisted ips for the same user.
With the config below login from an external ip works as expected but from a whitelisted ip it fails and I see this message.
Authenticated with partial success.
Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).

I believe the access file is having the desired effect skipping 2fa but then AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive fails.
Can keyboard-interactive be skipped when 2fa is skipped?
My current config looks like this
/etc/pam.d/sshd
# success=1 skips pam_google_authenticator when local ip
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-local.conf
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so

access-local.conf where ### is a local ip
+ : ALL : ###.###.###.### 
- : ALL : ALL

/etc/ssh/sshd_config
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive

I do have an alternative that works and proves my point about keyboard-interactive but wanted to use an access file.
Match address ###.###.###.###
  AuthenticationMethods publickey

Match all
  AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive


KeyboardInteractive (formelly ChallengeResponse) is the only authentication mechanism in SSH protocoll that can be used to implement TOTP 2FA (the one which Google Authenticator implements). It's a generic chat-like authentication, in this case it's supposed to transfer one-time password code (rather than traditional PAM setup where an unencrypted user password is requested through it).

See here for more thorough explanation. My point was that nothing is skipped; your KbdInteractive is your 2FA, so when you see the report that KbdInteractive fails it's because the 2FA PAM plugin reports failure.
